# Trying to place a trigger order in Bitget via API

Tags: python, python-requests, exchange-server

I am trying to place a trigger order on Bitget using the API.

So far I have this but this returns error

> {'code': '43011', 'msg': 'The parameter does not meet the specification clientOid non
> conformance', 'requestTime': 1697897375121, 'data': None}

I've been trying for ages but just can't get any further. The pass, secret , key are all fine also.

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64
import requests
import json
import time

api_key = "key here"
secret_key = "secret"
passphrase = "pass"
base_url = "https://api.bitget.com"
endpoint = "/api/mix/v1/plan/placePlan"

# Define the payload

payload = {"symbol": "BTCUSDT_UMCBL","marginCoin": "USDT","size": "0.001","executePrice": "33145.5","triggerPrice":"33145.5","side":"open_long","orderType":"limit","triggerType":"market_pr ice","clientOid":"test@483939290000"}



# Convert the payload to JSON format
payload_str = json.dumps(payload)

# Generate the signature
timestamp = str(int(time.time() * 1000))
message = timestamp + "POST" + endpoint + payload_str
signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(secret_key.encode('utf-8'), message.encode('utf-8'), 
hashlib.sha256).digest())

# Set the request headers
headers = {
"ACCESS-KEY": api_key,
"ACCESS-SIGN": signature,
"ACCESS-TIMESTAMP": timestamp,
"ACCESS-PASSPHRASE": passphrase,
"Content-Type": "application/json"
}

# Send the request
response = requests.post(base_url + endpoint, headers=headers, data=payload_str)

# Print the response
print(response.json())
```